# Hive connectivity issue in Superset

Tags: apache-superset

Hive connectivity issue in Superset (ERROR: Could not load database driver: BaseEngineSpec)

I am trying to add a hive db in Superset providing the conneciton string containing http path, but getting ERROR: Could not load database driver: BaseEngineSpec

Example string i am using:
hive2://dbaddress:port/default;ssl=true;transportMode=http;httpPath=default/hive but